# Datagridview column value displaying issue

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am unable to resolve the following issue:

- Connect to Excel (oledb connection)
- Fetch all data to the `datagridview`

Example source fetched from Excel (Col1 to Col3 Excel properties are "General", Col4 is Date specific):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Text1   1.5 288.77  3/1/2013
Text2   1.3 352.47  3/1/2013
Text3   1a  206.93  3/1/2013
Text4   1   206.93  3/1/2013
Text5   1   206.93  3/1/2013
```

- Once data is in `datagridview`
  (`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns=True`), it seems to take for
  granted that `Col2` contains integers ONLY and does not display the
  cell value which is not an integer.

Example fetched from datagridview:

```
   Col1 Col2    Col3    Col4
    Text1   1.5 288.77  3/1/2013
    Text2   1.3 352.47  3/1/2013
    Text3       206.93  3/1/2013
    Text4   1   206.93  3/1/2013
    Text5   1   206.93  3/1/2013
```

- The actual issue is that I am validating the data in the datagridview
  against an XML file and am proving a log which gives the user rowID
  and the actual source value. I cannot seem to get that same value out
  of the datagridview.
- The only partial solution I have found so far is to explicitly
  convert all Excel fields to text, but that obviously messes up some
  of the fields (example: date field).

How do I get to fetch ALL SOURCE FILE values inside the datagridview and then perform all subsequent data validation tasks?

Comment: Can not even read this. format a little.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting issue - should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to only fetch Excel raw data (as it is formatted in the Excel sheet) into datagridview for displaying purposes and then perform additional data validation.
I would suggest to use the intermixed columns connection string example (IMEX) below:

```
strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                        "Data Source=" + strFilePath + ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'";
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed - fetch the data as it is and then proceed with whatever validation is requested.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a DataTable with data columns having the desired types then get the data into the DataTable. Finally, bind the DataTable to the DataGridview

Comment: Thanks Tarik, here is one further clarification - I use this for different types of data, so it is supposed to be dynamic. I cannot set exact number of columns and types as these might differ based on the source.

Comment: Do you have any way of determining the column data types in advance?

Comment: I meant, can you determine the column type at run time when reading the data from Excel?

Answer (score 0):

[read-a-excel-file-with-sheet-wise-into-dataset-using-csharp](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code972-read-a-excel-file-with-sheet-wise-into-dataset-using-csharp-.aspx) may be helpful for you.
You really do not need to know any thing about the data in the file to build a usable table.

Comment: This is a valid way of reading an Excel file, however Ventsislav's answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: No Problem glad you got what you needed.